# Como traduzir as mensagens de erro do codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework

Galera, como eu faço para traduzir as mensagens de erro que o codeigniter exibe? A onde eu posso baixar os arquivos e como configurar? Desde já fico grato! vlw.

Comment: Tem um exemplo de mensagem ai?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070227/translating-codeigniters-form-validation-error-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

baixa a tradução no [github.com](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Translation) joga dentro de `app\language` e altera o arquivo `app\config\config.php`, procure pela linha `$config['language']   = 'nome_da_pasta';` e altere o `nome_da_pasta` igual ao que você baixou na documentação do codeigniter